# Storing an Externally Generated Private Key on EC2 Linux

Tags: linux, ssh, python

We have been given the public & private keys to connect to an external (outside our firewall) WSFTP site.  We need to use this/these keys to connect this vendor's WSFTP and pull the data into our systems.

We are using a RHEL Linux instance.  And trying to write the process to connect & pull the data using Python.  Something like this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42480787/loading-selected-file-from-sftp-to-s3-using-python

The question I have is how do we take the ieys provided to use and store them on our system such that they will work during a connect statement (See below).

```
import datetime, gspread, json, paramiko

# Variable Set Up
hostname = 'HOST.NAME'
myuser = 'USER.NAME'
mySSHK = 'PATH.To.Key'

# Actual Script (no changes should be needed)
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(hostname, username=myuser, key_filename=mySSHK)
```

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed by having the individual who created the key using puttygen on a windows instance, export the key as an OpenSSL key.

Copy Paste that information into ~/.ssh/id_rsa, and it worked beautifully.  Apologizes for the noise.  Hope this helps at least one other person.